# How to solve 3 variables problem with logarithm term

Tags: logarithms

Given three equation

$$\log{(2xy)} = (\log{(x)})(\log{(y)})$$
$$\log{(yz)} = (\log{(y)})(\log{(z)})$$
$$\log{(2zx)} = (\log{(z)})(\log{(x)})$$

Find the real solution of (x, y, z)

What should I do to get the answer? and I think it's not possible that x = y = z has a solution, I have no idea what method I can do. Show me a hint

Comment: Do you miss a $\log(2)$ in the second line?

Comment: Let $A=\log x, B=\log y, C=\log z$.  Now use the properties of the log to rewrite your equations in terms of $A,B, C$.

Comment: No, the equation is definetely written just like that in my book. And that's why I feel like there's a mistake in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\log abc = \log a + \log b + \log c$

If you then substitute $\log x = a$, $\log y = b$, $\log z = c$, you get an equation in $a, b, c$ which is easier to solve.

As suggested, I would check the second equation-is a 2 missing?

Answer (score 0):

Set $a=\log x$, $b=\log y$, $c=\log z$ then solve

- $\log 2+a+b=ab$
- $b+c=bc$
- $\log 2+a+c=ac$

subtracting the first and the third

- $b-c=a(b-c) \implies a=1 \lor b=c$

but $a=1$ is not acceptable then $b=c$.